# What is the PowerShell equivalent of ksh's `whence -v`?

Tags: powershell

From a comment at http://www.davidarno.org/2008/04/08/pash-powershell-for-the-rest-of-us/:

> With the ksh, I could type `whence -v cd` to determine that `cd` was a tracked alias of say `/bin/cd`. In PowerShell, `cd` is an alias of `Set-Location`, but I only found this out because I typed `help cd`, and got the `Set-Location` help page. The `whence -v` command would report whether the item was a function, alias, tracked alias, or give the file location.

How can we do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Get-Command` cmdlet, which has a convenient alias `gcm`:

```
> Get-Command cd

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Alias           cd -> Set-Location
```